# Twisted Protocol Instance Variables?

Tags: python, oop, networking, twisted

CLIENT:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol

class EchoClient(protocol.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg

    def connectionMade(self):
        self.transport.write("hello, world!")

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        print "Server said:", data
        self.transport.loseConnection()

    def connectionLost(self, reason):
        print "connection lost"

class EchoFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = EchoClient

    def buildProtocol(self, address):
        proto = protocol.ClientFactory.buildProtocol(self, address, 12)
        self.connectedProtocol = proto
        return proto

    def clientConnectionFailed(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection failed - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

    def clientConnectionLost(self, connector, reason):
        print "Connection lost - goodbye!"
        reactor.stop()

def main():
    f = EchoFactory()
    reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 8000, f)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

SERVER:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from twisted.internet import reactor, protocol
from twisted.application import service, internet

class Echo(protocol.Protocol):
    def dataReceived(self, data):
        self.transport.write(data)

def main():
    factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
    factory.protocol = Echo
    reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ERROR:

```
exceptions.TypeError: buildProtocol() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

QUESTION:

How can I get the `EchoClient` class in the `CLIENT` to accept parameters and assign instance variables ( such as arg in the `EchoClient` constructor above)?  As noted below, it was previously suggested that I override the `buildProtocol` function, but my attempt at doing so has lead me to the above error.  I am not really sure where to go from here.  I suppose my question can be generalize to: how can I add instance variables to a protocol?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you wrote:

```
def buildProtocol(self, address):
    proto = protocol.ClientFactory.buildProtocol(self, address, 12)
```

that is, you are overriding `ClientFactory.buildProtocol` and calling the parent class with a different signature than it knows how to handle.

Passing data from the factory to the client is only a little tricky.  You can provide any `__init__` you want to the factory, but twisted creates instances of `IProtocol` itself.  Fortunately, most factories assign themselves to the `factory` attribute of the protocol, once it's ready to go:

```
class MyClientProtocol(protocol.Protocol):
    def connectionMade(self):
        # use self.factory here:
        self.transport.write(self.factory.arg)

class MyClientFactory(protocol.ClientFactory):
    protocol = MyClientProtocol

    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.arg = arg
```

In fact, the whole ProtocolFactory business is to support this kind of use; but be mindful; many instances of `Protocol` will share a single instance of their factory; use the factory for *configuration* but manage *state* in the protocol.

It's certainly possible that the way the standard family of Protocol/Factory implementations don't suit your needs, and that's also reasonable, so long as you fully implement the `IProtocol` and `IProtocolFactory` interfaces.  The base classes exist because they handle most of the cases for you, not because they are the only possible implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear from your question what *exactly* your tryed and what *exactly* the error was, but anyway you have to do two steps:

1. Make `EchoClient`'s constructor take whatever arguments you need it to take and initialise whatever field you need it to initialise.
2. Override `buildProtocol` method in your factory to supply those arguments to your protocol.